# Pandas : KeyError due to datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, keyerror

In a script, I consider a subset (of rows) of a pandas dataframe, do some operations on it and assign back to the whole dataframe.
But in some cases, the subset is actually the dataframe itself, and then I got this error :

```
"KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]""
```

I noticed that it is due to a datetime column (if I drop this column, the error disappears).
To illustrate, I repeated this error on a minimal case. Here is my dataframe :

```
df = 
                      time        ip
165840 2023-06-10 14:57:38    9.1371
165841 2023-06-10 14:59:34    4.0609
165842 2023-06-10 15:01:32   18.2741
165843 2023-06-10 15:03:29   30.9645
165844 2023-06-10 15:06:36   52.7919
165845 2023-06-10 15:08:33   61.4213
165846 2023-06-10 15:10:29   78.1726
165847 2023-06-10 15:12:26   87.8173
165848 2023-06-10 15:14:23  104.5685
```

However, when I do the following : `df[df.ip < 1000] = df[df.ip < 1000]` (which is equivalent to assigning df to itself, I got the mentioned error.
It is like the type of 'time' column changes.

I also tried to do the assignment with iloc, but I got this warning for all cases (non only when subset is the whole dataframe):

```
 DeprecationWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you expect to achieve by this line of code?

Comment: `df[df.ip < 1000] = df[df.ip < 1000]` works for me.  What version of `pandas` are you using?  What is `df.columns`?  What is `df.dtypes`?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine on my side. I guess there is some issue with the pandas version.
So far these are working fine for me.

```
df[df.ip < 1000] = df[df.ip < 1000]
```

or

```
condition = df['ip'] < 1000
df.loc[condition, :] = df.loc[condition, :]
```

[Official Documentation for Pandas to check versions](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)